# How to create re-usable blocks in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

**Scenario:**

I have a serverless/cloudformation script that re-deploys the same code with different configurations to AWS as lambdas and exposes each lambda via API Gateway.

So far the only way I've been able to do this is via copious amounts of copy and paste within the same script.. but its starting to drive me up the walls... thus, as I'm a complete newby to AWS and, navigating the AWS docs and internet has yielded pretty bad results, in answering this... I'm trying my luck here.

**Within a cloudformation script:**

```
"Resources":{  
   "LambdaResourceNG":{  
      "Type":"AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties":{  
         "Handler":"some-handlername::foo::bar",
         "Runtime":"dotnetcore2.0",
         "Environment":{  
            "Variables":{  
               "PictureOptions__OriginalPictureSuffix":{  
                  "Fn::Join":[  
                     "",
                     [  
                        "_",
                        "ng",
                        "_",
                        {  
                           "Fn::FindInMap":[  
                              "Environments",
                              {  
                                 "Ref":"EnvironmentValue"
                              },
                              "PictureOptionsOriginalPictureSuffix"
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  ]
               },

            },
            "Events":{  
               "Bar":{  
                  "Type":"Api",
                  "Properties":{  
                     "Path":"/ng/bar",
                     "Method":"POST"
                  }
               },
               "Foo":{  
                  "Type":"Api",
                  "Properties":{  
                     "Path":"/ng/foo",
                     "Method":"POST"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
   }
```

**Question:**

In the script block above.. The resource is called `LambdaResourceNG`. If I wanted to have another resource...`LambdaResourceKE`... with all appropriate sections changed to `KE`. How would I make a "function" that I could re-use within this erm... language?

I've already found out how to use maps to swap out variables based on some env value... but how would one go about creating reusable blocks of code/config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the existing CloudFormation [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html) feature doesn't suffice and you need real programmability then the final CF template can be the output of a higher-level process.

There are tools available to create templates e.g. [AWS Cloud Development Kit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html), [Troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) and [cfndsl](https://github.com/cfndsl/cfndsl).

Another option would be to drive the creation of the final template from a CLI. It doesn't have to be particularly sophisticated, just something that includes a template engine (like jinja2 or handlebars). Then you can program the inclusion of reusable template fragments, dynamically inject values into those fragments, iterate over loops as necessary, and emit a final CloudFormation template (or a main template and set of nested templates).

Comment: Wow that perfect. I agree.. it seemed super messy for me to just throw everything into that one file. Some context, when creating my lambda initially (I'm a C# dev)... it included a `serveless.tempate` file... I only recently realized that is is in actual fact a CF script. Those 2 template tools you linked seem like they'll get the job done. Thanks again :)

Comment: One thing to verify before committing to template generators like troposphere or cfndsl is that they are up to date and support the AWS resources that you want to generate. The tools are generally some way behind the pace of AWS.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest a CloudFormation Stack within another using the [AWS::CloudFormation::Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) resource type. Nested stacks cannot exist without their parent, deleting the parent stack will delete all nested stacks. Note that the `TemplateURL` must point to S3, and that is where the `aws cloudformation package` [CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) helps by uploading a local file there and replacing the URL in the template.

[Cross-stack references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) also helps in modularizing templates. For example, a "database network" stack can export the subnet ids and other values for any future database stack to use. Note that modularization goes further than merging text, but declaring and managing the resources lifecycle relationships correctly.

Stacks can even be composed further and across different regions and accounts using [StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html). This may be quite helpful when managing applications provisioned per tenant or sub-organization. This is frequently the case in "self-service IT" that can be achieved using CloudFormation with other services like [AWS Service Catalog](https://aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/) and [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace).

Answer (score 2):

Nested stacks are clumsy in that you don't necessarily want an entire stack just for a single resource. CloudFormation [Modules](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/introducing-aws-cloudformation-modules/) would solve this problem nicely ([reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/modules.html)). You can even package multiple resources in a single module.

You can create reusable modules with pre-packaged properties, which:

1. Reduce boilerplate configuration
2. Enforce company-wide standards

Modules are deployed to [CloudFormation Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/registry.html), where they can be versioned and used by anyone in your company. You can use Parameters in the module to pass in properties just like you would a standard AWS resource. You can then create the custom modules like this:

```yaml
Resources:
  LambdaResourceNG:
    Type: YourCompany::LambdaApi::FooBarApi
    Properties:
      ApiName: ng
  LambdaResource:
    Type: YourCompany::LambdaApi::FooBarApi
    Properties:
      ApiName: ke
```

Comment: Oh wow! So this is fairly new? Don't think this was out at the time of asking. But I'll def keep it in mind. Thanks for the update / new answer to this.

Comment: Yes, CF Modules were launched late 2020. I started using them and so far so good!

Answer (score 1):

To create a reusable template in Cloudformation. There are couple of things you need to keep in mind

1. `Use Nested stack` : using nested stack you can create a small stack for each AWS Service ( i.e VPC,LoadBalancer ), which you can use in other projects
2. `Use Parameters` : Use perameters as much as possible
3. `Use Conditions` : AWS Cloudformation provide solution to add conditions, Using Conditions we can use same template to perform multiple tasks